# Como puedo saber la version de .Net que esta usando una aplicacion en el IIS?

Tags: c#, .net, iis, windows-server-2016

Nosotros hemos migrado un aplicacion de la version de Net 3.5 a la 4.8. La verdad es que estamos encontrando muchos problemas. Todo parece correcto, pero parece no funcionar, devuelve un error 500 sin mas informacion. Mi approach es que no esta corriendo con la version de Net correcta. Por ello instale la version 4.8 del siguiente enlace:
[Net 4.8 Framework](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/microsoft-net-framework-4-8-offline-installer-for-windows-9d23f658-3b97-68ab-d013-aa3c3e7495e0)
para Windows Server 2016. Sigue sin funcionar. Aun tengo mis dudas, como puedo saber que version de Net 4.8 esta utilizando mi aplicacion, teniendo en cuenta que no tengo acceso a Windows Features?

Os sirve de algo esta informacion de configuracion de la APP en el IIS?

[image: IIS]

Comment: Habeis cambiado en el administrador del IIS la versión de Net Framework de la propia aplicación? Si cambias la version de la aplicación pero no la de la aplicación web puede que sea ese el problema que tienes

Comment: @Marc. Hemos cambiado la configuracion de la app pool a CLR Net 4. Te refieres a eso?

Comment: Si, me referia a eso, el CLR Net 4 es la version que tienes que tener seleccionada para todos los Net Framweork 4.X, asi que si lo tienes configurado de esta manera lo tienes bien, debe ir por otro lado el error que comentas.

Comment: @Marc. Vaya. Ok, gracias.